# OpenLayers WMS overlay tile projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2

We are using OpenLayers for our GIS Application and we have base files from Ordinance Survey for UK maps.

For creating WMS layers, we are generating tiles of 256 x 256 through Sharpmap Library but facing issues when the base layer is Google or Bing.

We know Google uses EPSG:900913 projection and we are able to transform the projection from EPSG:900913 to OSGB36 successfully. For this we are using GeoTools.js methods to achieve the transformation.

But the issue is that the tiles being created are not projected properly. There is a slight misalignment at the connecting point of each tile with other tile.

Comment: Would you not be better off going the other way and transforming the OS data to 900913?

Comment: It sounds like a violation of the Google ToS to go in this direction.